# Strange behavior of x * POW(10,y). A very small decimal at end. What's better for simple integers?

Tags: mysql

When I do this query:

```
SELECT 
12*POW(10,-1),POW(10,-1),12*0.1,
11*POW(10,-1),POW(10,-1),11*0.1;`
```

I get this result:

```
1.2000000000000002  0.1 1,2 1.1 0.1 1,1
```

What the ..?
Not only am I surprised by the very small decimal 2 in the first column and nót in the third column, do you see the comma's there where there should be dots (resp 3d, last column) (or vice versa but not the two mixed)?
The first problem also occurs with 14, 17 and other numbers, but not with all!
**My questions**

1. Bug or do I need some explanation?
2. If it's a float issue, why not give precision error in 2nd and 3d
   column?
3. Why once comma and other times dot?
4. What's the best solution regarding performance (process time in very big table)? (even if I have to re"type' my columns)
   Then I mean for a number that doesn't really need a float column, like this:
    **X * 10^y** 
   whereby X=integer and y=integer between -4 to +4

**EDIT:** 
**Question 4 resolution**
Since I probably went a bit too far with my edits, I'll accept the answer below and post my own resolve about question 4 here: I decided to convert my columns to DECIMAL(9,3). Though it meant the storage requirement will go from 3 bytes to 4 bytes, I guess it's the best solution for not having to do a lot of CONVERT() and POW() afterwards.

Comment: SQLFiddle does not do that.

Comment: @echo_Me: What is said below ofc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet again - it is about floating point precision. [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) data types, such as [FLOAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html) in MySQL - store values approximately **by definition** . And your result will be in `float` data type since [`POW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_pow) will return floating-point result.

That means, values of that data types are represented with some precision, but not obligatory with exact value. Precision, actually, depends of data type itself (for example, double holds double precision). Thus, such things should not surprise you. You should be aware of that and operate on values if floating-point data types carefully.

*Update*:

Since you've updated your question, I'll be more specific:

- No, it is not a bug - and explanation above fits this
- Displaying values has nothing to do with their representation. Your 1-st, 2-nd and 3-rd values are all represented approximately *(you just can't always see it)*
- This is strange. Are you sure that it's exactly the query you've run?:

```
mysql> select @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 5.5.27    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT 
    -> 12*POW(10,-1),POW(10,-1),12*0.1,
    -> 11*POW(10,-1),POW(10,-1),11*0.1; 
+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+
| 12*POW(10,-1)      | POW(10,-1) | 12*0.1 | 11*POW(10,-1) | POW(10,-1) | 11*0.1 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+
| 1.2000000000000002 |        0.1 |    1.2 |           1.1 |        0.1 |    1.1 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

- Best for what? Avoiding approximate representation? But that is how floating-point data types work. However, you can [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) your result directly to [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) data type:

  `SELECT CONVERT(12*POW(10,-1), DECIMAL(4,1))`

`DECIMAL` is fixed-point data type, so you'll avoid problems that you have in your case, but keep in mind that fixed-point data types hold values with predefined precision (that goes from definition) - so you'll have only certain count of signing digits.

Comment: I thought of that, but why does it then not occur with 11 and does with 12 ?  Is it because of some bit calculation? But then where is the fault as avery single part of the solution is put in the 2d and 3d column, which indicates it's not about floats.
I mean if it's a float issue, mysql should make certain it has the same error for the same function.
And what about the solution?  Should I put a CONVERT() somewhere or what is the best solution? (As in performance-and-code-beauty best)

Comment: Because of I've written. _Not all values_ can be represented precisely means that values, that _can be_ represented precisely, exist. I.e. some values will be represented precisely and some - will not. But since we're speaking about common case - you should keep that in mind and do not rely on precise representation in operations with floating-point values

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my comment a bit meanwhile. So I'll ask again:
1. IF it's float problem, why does the 2nd and 3d column not give a precision error, because they are each part of the 1st column calculation ?
2. What is the best solution without having to do big float calculations (for 12E-1)?

Comment: @R-U-Bn 2-nd and 3-rd also are approximately represented. If you see something 'without small decimal part' - that does not mean that value is represented precisely. Displaying values has nothing to do with their representation. The 'best solution' is to remember about that and compare floats carefully (with some precision delta, like `1E-13`)

Comment: OK, I see now with the representation. I still find it wrong that it's not consistent, but OK, that's mysql's way.
There is still 2 remaining questions (I'll put them in the post for clarity to, but) 1. What with the dot and comma? 2. What's the best solution for exponents (10^x with x from -4 to +4)?

Comment: I don't know about 'dot' and 'commas'. Result will be floats in any case (for me it returned dots as it's expected). And I don't know about 'best solution'. Best for what?

Comment: Weird that I have that comma and dot problem and you don't.
Best for what? -> Best to have no precision erros, and for not having to use round() and maybe pow() at all. So best for sql performance and process-time to get this formula from a lot of rows. See post edit.

Comment: I guess my chat trial didn't work (StackOverflow proposed it).
Yes, I am sure about the comma and dot differences. Don't know if it's navicat that I use or my mysql, but I am satisified to know it's at my end.
About: CONVERT(X*POW(10,Y),DECIMAL(10,4)), I find it is too process-heavy for a simple thing with integers and only multiplications of 10 (max 4 both directions) and I am wondering if there is no better alternative. (I really don't know, but maybe string manupilation or other tricks or functions.)

Comment: For the record, I found the console command in navicat, and it seems the dot and comma problem to be mysql's fault after all:
SELECT 17*POW(10,-1),POW(10,-1),11*0.1;
+--------------------+------------+--------+
| 17*POW(10,-1)      | POW(10,-1) | 11*0.1 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+
| 1.7000000000000002 |        0.1 | 1,1    |
+--------------------+------------+--------+
1 row in set